# ajax half star rating control

Tags: asp.net, ajax, controls, rating

Is there a half-star rating control I can use for asp.net/ajax

Comment: dont forget to mark answwer as accpeted if you got the info you want..

Answer (score 1):

[AJAX ASP.NET Rating Control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/AjaxRating.aspx)
output :

[image]